# Digital Ocean and GMAIL smtp server give error

Tags: symfony, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer, digital-ocean

I am using **Symfony2** on **Digital Ocean Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS** (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual i686).
*Everything is working on my localhost*, but *do not work on Digital Ocean Server*, 
Here is error message when I try to register user in my web with Activation Email enabled :

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException
```

and error stacktrace :

```
    $this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create($options));
    if (false === $this->_stream) {
        throw new Swift_TransportException(
            'Connection could not be established with host '.$this->_params['host'].
            ' ['.$errstr.' #'.$errno.']'
            );
```

Output from server terminal :

```
yusuf@xwzxc:~$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 74.125.130.108...
Trying 74.125.130.109...
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c01::6c...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to curb spam and abuse, some new user accounts at DigitalOcean have their SMTP ports blocked by default. Unfortunately there are sometimes false positives. It sounds like this might have been the case for you. If you open a [support ticket](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/support), the team would be happy to remove that block for you

Comment: It is not true anymore. Support tells you to wait 60 days now.
And it's crazy. How i can do services without smtp these days? Digital Ocean no more!

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I have changed the smtp.gmail.com by the IP
You can get the IP by: `ping smtp.gmail.com` on the command line.